# Get data-id of anchor element inside a li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Html

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" data-id="1" onclick="clickFunction();"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" data-id="2" onclick="clickFunction();"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" data-id="3" onclick="clickFunction();"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" data-id="4" onclick="clickFunction();"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" data-id="5" onclick="clickFunction();"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My app got a list of things then after 5secs. it will automatically go to the next li.
but that is not the problem. the problem is with the click function I want to know the data-id of the li.

Comment: Did you realize the `data-id` is used in your `a` elements?

Comment: You're using jQuery, stop using `onclick` attribute and create [`click` event handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for your `a` tag.

Comment: @PranavCBalan the problem is I want be able to get the data-id of the next li. which is what i want to get

Comment: @Ele won't I be able to get the data-id on the anchor element?

Comment: @Mikey is there a difference?

Comment: Do you want to get the `data-id` from the `links` or from the `li`?

Comment: @Ele if I will place my data-id in my li. How do I get it in Jquery?

Comment: @franzjoseph `onclick` attribute is a very old way of doing things and would require you to write a bunch of ugly code just to get to the next element. The whole purpose of jQuery is to make JavaScript DOM manipulation easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## According to the OP's comments

- Remove the `onclick attribute`.
- Bind the `click` event using jQuery.
- Use `closest('li')` to get the parent of your links.

```js
function clickFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // This is to prevent the execution of your links!
  console.log($(this).closest('li').data('id'));
}

$('a').click(clickFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-id="1">
    <a href="">1</a>
  </li>
  <li data-id="2">
    <a href="">2</a>
  </li>
  <li data-id="3">
    <a href="">3</a>
  </li>
  <li data-id="4">
    <a href="">4</a>
  </li>
  <li data-id="5">
    <a href="">5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Remove `onclick` attribute.

(2) Attach a .click handler to all your links

```
$(function () {
    // attach an onclick event handler to your links
    $('li a[data-id]').click(function (e) {
      // prevent the link from going anywhere
      e.preventDefault();
      // get the parent li
      var li = $(this).closest('li');
      // get next li's link data id
      console.log(li.next('li').find('a').data('id'));
   });
});
```

Comment: let me try this.